# Change default path powerpoint conversion

Tags: environment, powerpoint-services

The default path to store temporary files from PowerPoint conversion is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\PowerPointConversion\
```

Is there a way to change this path (entire or part would be useful) ?

Comment: is it open in the powerpoint application?

Comment: I think you have to change from CLient application, check this if help...let us know http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2013/03/sharepoint-change-default-for-my-local.html

Comment: Actually I am aiming to change the temporary directory used by SharePoint to convert Power Point files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem just keeping the directory where it is, but creating a link to another device that I am actually using to store this data.

I have followed this tutorial to create to create this link. This task is not trivial and easy when it does changes on C:\ProgramData directory. But it worked like a charm.

- https://superuser.com/a/510628/399778

A second step to make a healthy environment was to setup a auto-cleaning task. I did it using this tutorial:

- http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/10/31/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-delete-all-the-files-in-a-folder-older-than-90-days.aspx

Comment: Thanks Leandro for posting your workaround here - very helpful. Do you know whether PP automation service does any cleanup on 'PowerPointConversion' folder? Do they live there forever - for us to do the cleanup??

Comment: Hi! Yes, live forever. I did not found any built-in way to run this auto-cleanup task, so I have defined a custom script to do that. Here you can find a complete reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/10/31/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-delete-all-the-files-in-a-folder-older-than-90-days.aspx